# Translating Lotus Notes non-Mail design possible with convert?

Tags: lotus-notes

If not, does anyone know of another tool that can do this?  Or do I need to learn German and Portuguese to do my migration from Notes to MOSS?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to translate German & Portuguese to English or redesigning a Notes database in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

The option you are looking for is -g'German' (or -gGerman on Linux)
See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21304939) for all options, or check the document "Upgrading mail files with the mail conversion utility" in your Administrator- Help.

Excerpt from the help:

```
Convert the English mail template design to a non-English language, for example German: 
  load convert -g"German" TestMail.nsf * mail9_en_de.ntf
Note: On the Linux™ platform, do not use quotes around the requested language name. 
Example syntax for Linux is as follows:
  load convert -gGerman TestMail.nsf * mail9.ntf
```

Although this example speaks of mail- databases explicitely, this works for any multilingual database.

Unfortunately these options only work, if the database uses the IBM standard method to have multilingual databases (One design element for any language). You find out, if a database / template is "Multilingual" by checking the Properties of the database. On the fourth tab there is a section "Multilingual database". If this is enabled in the template, then you can use convert task to switch the language. Otherwise it is not possible and you have to do the translation manually.

Take care: This (of course) only translates the design of the database, NOT the content of the documents contained within the database.

Unfortunately there are very few databases, that use this translation- method (e.g. Discussion, Teamroom, Resource Reservation), but almost any "custom" database does not use this...